# Is there a way to tell if the Foreground Window is graphical or Commandline?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, win32gui

I am currently making a program that will behave differently depending if the Foreground Window is CMD-like or GUI. How would I go about getting this information though?

```
win32gui.GetWindowType(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow())
```

or something similar is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Check the window class name against `"ConsoleWindowClass"`. Don't know it's ever been officially documented, but that's been the case for a long time (before that, it used to be `"tty"` in Win9x).

Comment: That sounds like an odd requirement. Sure, you can call [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to get the process ID, [OpenProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) to get a handle, and [GetProcessImageFileNameW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew) to find the executable image. Though there is nothing in the system that would report whether a process is *"CMD-like"*.

Comment: `win32gui.GetClassName(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow() ) == 'ConsoleWindowClass' ` really works, thanks to @dxiv

Comment: @IInspectable comparing the file path to `cmd.exe` or `command.com` assumes a custom command processor is not installed.  At the very least, you could compare the file path against the `%COMSPEC%` environment variable.

Comment: @rem I didn't suggest how to go from executable image path name to *"is this CMD-like?"*. I don't know what *"CMD-like"* means to the OP, so they will have to codify their requirements as needed. Even in case there is no custom command processor installed, there are still **loads** of different console hosts available (e.g. Windows Terminal) you'd have to account for. And lots of other cases, where this won't do. What should the implementation report in case VSCode is the foreground window, with the integrated terminal having input focus? What if a VM host is the foreground window?

Comment: CMD-like basically means anything that just excepts commands, and isn't graphical (e.g. cmd.exe). I'll have to try the methods listed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was stated in the comments, but figured I'd put it in the answers tab too.

```
win32gui.GetClassName(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) == "ConsoleWindowClass"
```